# Heroku Springboot error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku

Al deployar mi proyecto en heroku deploya todo correctamente pero tira este error:

> 2019-08-07T03:06:05.379929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2019-08-07T03:06:05.269613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
>   2019-08-07T03:06:05.269701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
>   2019-08-07T03:06:05.356959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
>   2019-08-07T03:06:06.511761+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gestor-web-service.herokuapp.com request_id=42a5cb23-66fa-4619-9aa3-2501710e1b22 fwd="181.44.185.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Mi Procfile:

> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.techprimers.SpringBootDemoApplication -Dserver.port=$PORT

---

Mi Procfile:

web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.techprimers.SpringBootDemoApplication -Dserver.port=$PORT

Comment: Lucas, ¿es posible que nos entregues más información sobre lo que estás desplegando?

Answer (score 1):

Lo logre.
Ya funciona.
Conclusión cambie el pom.xml y tambien el ProcFile
Agregue al pom esto.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             </plugin>
        </plugins>                
    </build>
```

Y mi ProcFile quedo asi.

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/spring-boot-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

y funciono.

Comment: tal vez quieras aceptar tu propia respuesta :)